# Can't change RootFolder of ASPxFileManager control using Callback method

Tags: devexpress, file-manager

I'm using DevExpress 13.1 to develop my web application. My page has two controls: A Gridview which contains some item and a FileManager control (is children of a callbackpanel) which contain files information of item which is focused on that Gridview. I'm using Gridview's FocusRowChange client event to get data and send it back to server through an callback (of callback panel) to set new RootFolder value, but it not works. Tell me where's my wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

My code:

ASPX file:

```
    function myGridView_FocusRowChanged(s, e) { 
      var index = s.GetFocusedRowIndex();                                                
      var soCT = s.GetRowValues(index,"SoChungThu;SoHopDong",LoadFileList);                       
    }
    function LoadFileList(values) {    
      myCallbackPanel.PerformCallback("CHANGE_ROOT_FOLDER" + "," + values);
    }
```

CS file:

```
protected void myCallbackPanel_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
        {
                var vals = e.Parameter.Split(',');
                if (vals[0].ToUpper() == "CHANGE_ROOT_FOLDER")
                {
                    var path = vals[0] + "/" + vals[1];
                    myFileManager.Settings.RootFolder = path;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Comment: The RootFolder still is "" when the callback event is fired on second time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Store folder path in Session, and assign it to RootFolder in Page_Load event.

Thank for reading.

Comment: Please mark your question as solved when you can, and congrats on solving it :)